# How to leave some marks in a regex pattern?

Tags: java, regex

I  have matched a string with a pattern using regex and after that I want to get strings in a certain positions in the original string
for example I have matched:

```
your name is Jon and you have 15 years and you live in Germany
```

using this pattern:

```
your\\s+name\\s+is\\s+\\w+\\s+and\\s+you\\s+have\\s+\\d+\\s+years\\s+and\\s+you\\s+live\\s+in\\s+\\w+
```

and I want to extract name = "Jon" , age = 15 and Country = "Germany". Is there any way to leave some marks in the pattern to find those specific strings ?

Comment: You need to use matching groups and backreferences.

Comment: What flavor regex are you using?

Comment: Are you talking about capture groups (parenthesis) or do you mean something different by "marks" ?

Comment: I use regex in java.

Comment: I want to leave a specific mark where some strings exist so that i can find them easily after matching

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is.
You can use a encapsulate your "marked" words in bracets as follows (the term for that is "capturegroup"):

```
your\s+name\s+is\s+(\w+)\s+and\s+you\s+have\s+(\d+)\s+years\s+and\s+you\s+live\s+in\s+(\w+)
```

Using the preg_match function of your respective language (for PHP its "preg_match") youll get 3 matches containing name, age and country.

I created a "fiddle" for u here:
http://regex101.com/r/tN5vH4/1

Comment: If you want to know all, the Java method you can use is `find` and the all the backslashes must be escaped (stupid language): `\\s+is\\s+(\\w+)...`

Answer (score 0):

Does order matter to you?

You can see this regex:

```
your name is (\S+)|you have (\d+) years|you live in (\S+)
```

on [this page](http://regex101.com/r/zO4nH6/2) where the input text is written in different order, and it matches all of them. The way to do that is to use the `|` pipe character to say "or", so "your name is ..."  OR  "you have ... years"  OR  "you live in ...".

Comment: I'm working on a java project that manages a data base using SQL statements I validate every string with regex and I want to separate every string to use the data inside I want to do that in an easy way,Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use a capturing group to "extract" each target:

```
String name = str.replaceAll(".*your name is (\\w+).*", "$1");
int age = Integer.parseInt(str.replaceAll(".*you have (\\d+) years.*", "$1"));
String city = str.replaceAll(".*you live in (\\w+).*", "$1");
```

This technique matches the entire input, but captures the target as group 1. The replacement is the captured group.